# Symfony 3 - Translation doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, twig, config, translation

(and sorry for my poor english)

I'm setting up translation on my project but impossible.

I would like to be able to translate my site in French, but it remains in English.

For the moment I only want to translate strings of characters in twig, without variables.

My parameters.yml :

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
```

And my config.yml :

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator: { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          "%secret%"
```

If I do : `dump($request->getLocale());die();` in my controller, I got : "fr"

So my config is good.

And in my twig :

```
<label>{{ 'cancel'|trans }}</label>
```

But it still shows me "cancel".

Also, if I fly over the twig code, my editor tells me: "Missing tranlation key".

I just want for the moment translate a string, without varialbes.

Does someone have an idea ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I had a similar error and wandered with invalid tags: no closing, no text without a tag ... When I sorted out the syntax it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're missing your translation files, where you define the translations.

You need to define them into specific locations, e.g. `/app/Resources/translations/messages.fr.yml`

For more information check the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-resource-locations).

Comment: I guess it's good but i have another error now :
`ErrorException in DriverFactory.php line 47:
You need to define a driver class`

Comment: @PeterArtoung If you don't find a solution for this issue you can ask another question